# How can I stop a single URL POST being changed to a GET redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have about 40 c# desktop applications that are doing a POST off to http://www.example.com/submit-bug for user generated bug reports.

However I've recently switched my website (where the POST data is handled) over to HTTPS so everything is now 301'ed to HTTPS via htaccess.

This also means that my POST to http://www.example.com/submit-bug is being 301'ed to https://www.example.com/submit-bug which causes all the POST data to be lost as it goes from POST to a GET redirect.

How can I tell htaccess to ignore the redirect with a post to http://www.example.com/submit-bug and just continue to do the normal index.php routing that Laravel uses.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of the L and P flags but they are either ignored or cause a 500/404 error.

This is my current htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)submit-bug(.*)
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove any redirections or rewrite regarding a POST, by adding at the beginning, before `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Excellent! So all I needed in the end was  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 

Bounty granted my friend :-)